# Shared Preferences values was not updated immediately

Tags: java, android, api, sharedpreferences

I get some data from api when user logs in  and I want to update some views values immediately.but using shared preferences does not work for first time and user should close the app and shared preferences values was updated in that case.How can I update retrieved values from api in another activities without closing apps?
Here is my code

```
public class AppController extends Application {
  public static SharedPreferences userSharedPreferences;
  public static SharedPreferences.Editor userEditor;

  public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        userSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("user", MODE_PRIVATE);
        //userSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        userEditor = userSharedPreferences.edit();
  }
}

public class ParseLogin {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonObject.toString());
        JSONObject resultObject = json.getJSONObject("Result");
        JSONObject baseObject = resultObject.getJSONObject("Base");
        //SharedPreferences.Editor userEditor = context.getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        SharedPreferences.Editor userEditor = AppController.userEditor;

        userEditor.putString("UserName", baseObject.getString("UserName"));
        userEditor.putString("MobileNumber", baseObject.getString("Mobile"));
        userEditor.putString("FirstName", baseObject.getString("FirstName"));
        userEditor.putString("LastName", baseObject.getString("LastName"));
        userEditor.putString("Avatar", baseObject.getString("Avatar"));
        userEditor.putString("Email", baseObject.getString("Email"));
        userEditor.putString("Gender", baseObject.getString("Gender"));
        userEditor.putString("Datebirth", baseObject.getString("Datebirth"));
        userEditor.apply();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("const", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("PaymentUrl", resultObject.getString("PaymentUrl"));
        editor.putString("FararuUrl", resultObject.getString("FararuUrl"));
        editor.putString("ForgetPasswordUrl", resultObject.getString("ForgetPasswordUrl"));
        editor.apply();
        Log.i("test_sp", AppController.userSharedPreferences.getString("FirstName", ""));
}

public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       mLoginViewModel.login(v, et_username.getText().toString(),
                            et_pass.getText().toString(), getContext()).observe(this,
                            new Observer<Boolean>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable Boolean isLogin) {
                            if (isLogin) {
                                mLoginViewModel.getBaseData().observe(LoginFragment.this,
                                        new Observer<Boolean>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onChanged(@Nullable Boolean aBoolean) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                                        getActivity().finish();
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.logsuccess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                    });
                 } else {
                   dialog.dismiss();
                 }
           }
        });
    }
}

public class LoginViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
  public LiveData<Boolean> getBaseData() {
        LoginRepository loginRepository = new LoginRepository();
        return loginRepository.getBaseData(getApplication());
  }
}

public class LoginRepository {
   public LiveData<Boolean> getBaseData(final Context context) {
        BaseService loginService = new BaseService();
        final MutableLiveData<Boolean> loginStatusLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        String token = context.getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("Api-Token", "");
        Log.i("token_val", token);
        Call<JsonObject> call = loginService.getRetrofit().create(UserLoginApi.class).getBaseData(token);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {

                try {
                    assert response.body() != null;
                    ParseLogin parseLogin = new ParseLogin();
                    int code = parseLogin.getCode(response.body());
                    if (code == 200) {
                        parseLogin.getBaseData(context, new JSONObject(response.body().toString()));
                        logUser(context);
                        loginStatusLiveData.postValue(true);
                        FireBaseRepository fireBaseRepository = new FireBaseRepository();
                        fireBaseRepository.sendFireBaseToken(context);
                        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "user is login");
                    } else if (code == 401 || code == 403) {
                        loginStatusLiveData.postValue(false);
                        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "401,403");
                    } else {
                        loginStatusLiveData.postValue(true);
                        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "other");
                    }

                } catch (JSONException | NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "json error");
                    Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage() + "");
                    loginStatusLiveData.postValue(true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), t.getMessage() + "");
                Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "failure error");
                loginStatusLiveData.postValue(true);
            }
        });
        return loginStatusLiveData;
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("user", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences pref = AppController.userSharedPreferences;
        String fname = pref.getString("FirstName", "");
        String lname = pref.getString("LastName", "");
        tv_username.setText(fname + " " + lname);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [apply()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) method to update the sharedpreference, it is async method.

If you want an immediate update of the data, use [commit()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#commit())